# Let $\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx$ be an inner product. If $f(p(x)) = p'(-15) +8p(-1)$ is a functional, find $r(x)$ such that $f(p(x)) = \langle p,r\rangle $.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\langle p,q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx$ be an inner product on $\mathbb{P}^2$. If $f(p(x)) = p'(-15) +8p(-1)$ is a linear functional, find the unique $r(x)$ such that $f(p(x)) = \langle p,r\rangle $ for all $p(x)\in \mathbb{P}^2$.

Note that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is the space of polynomial of degree less than two. I know that this problem is an application of the Riesz Representation Theorem, but I can't seem to solve it. So far, I found an orthonormal basis for the space and tried to write $r(x) = \sum_{n=1}^2{f(b_i)b_i}$ where $B_\perp = \{1,12x-6\}$, but the answer I got was incorrect. Suggestions?

Comment: Haven't checked in detail but here is a possibility for you to investigate.  Your basis is not orthonormal since $\langle 12x-6,12x-6\rangle=12\ne1$.  You should be able to use this basis anyway as it is orthogonal, but I think it would be easy to make a careless error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basis is not orthonormal. Since $1$ and $12x-6$ are orthogonal, what you need to do is to normalize $12x-6$. If your normalize $12x-6$, you should get the right result.

In this case, though, it is much easier to just find $r$ directly. That is, $r(x)=cx+d$, so 
$$
\langle ax+b,cx+d\rangle=\int_0^1(ax+b)(cx+d)=a\left(\frac c3+\frac d2\right)+b\left(\frac c2+d\right). 
$$
As $f(ax+b)=a+8(-a+b)=-7a+8b$, we need $c/3+d/2=-7$, $c/2+d=8$. This gives $c=-132$, $d=74$. So $r(x)=-132x+74$.

Comment: Thank you. I did try this process and got lost at the very last step. Now I understand!